Cant run python program
def decideReward(points):
    if not(isinstance(points, int)):
        decision = "invalid"
        print("Invalid input! You should provide an integer!")
        return decision
    if points < 0:
        decision = "invalid"
        print("Invalid input! You should provide a non-negative   integer!")
        return decision
    if points < 500:
        decision = "no reward"
    else:
        if points < 1500:
            decision = "appetiser"
        else:
            if points < 5000:
                decision = "main course"
            else:
                if points <= 10000:
                    decision = "fine dining set"
                else:
                    decision = "unable to earn > 10000"
    print("The reward is: " + decision)
    return decision`

this is the code og my file loyalty.py which is located at      '/Users/rakshitdhanda/Downloads/SQT_lab7_pack2/lab7'
Im trying to run this code in terminal , with
MacBook-Air ~ % cd /Users/rakshitdhanda/Downloads/SQT_lab7_pack2
 MacBook-Air SQT_lab7_pack2 % cd lab7
 MacBook-Air lab7 % python3 loyalty.py 
 MacBook-Air lab7 % decideReward(4000)

as my terminal input , im expecting a desired output of "main course" but keep getting the output "zsh: unknown file attribute: 4", please help me , new to python and terminal and been stuck at this for 2 days.

I recommend Getting started

python3 loyalty.py

This command tells Python to execute the loyalty.py file. Python will read the file, note that you defined a function, then exit. Now you are back in shell, and shell has no idea what you mean when you write
decideReward(4000)

You need to have the function invocation in Python code for anything to happen. Add decideReward(4000) at the end of loyalty.py instead of typing it at the shell prompt. Alternately, you can do
python3

to run interactive session, then inside it run
from loyalty import decideReward
decideReward(4000)

You can exit from Python interactive session using ctrl-D (or ctrl-Z on Windows), or by running exit().

Threre are few issues in your code.
First of all as Amadan said - you are executing a program by using python3 loyality.py command and there is no output because even though you wrote the function you never invoked it. Threre are two ways of using your code. Either by using shell or in the file itself.
If you want to invoke the function on it's own
add following lines under your function:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    decideReward(4000)

so that your function will be actually used.
My other suggestions as for a python newbie are:

use less indentations - there is something called elif in python and it's combination of else and if. Example how your code would look like:

if points < 500:
    decision = "no reward"
elif 500 <= points < 1500:
    decision = "appetiser"
elif 1500 <= points < 5000:
    decision = "main course"
elif 5000 <= points <= 10000:
    decision = "fine dining set"

Notice that i used X < points < Y? This might also make your code more readable as is means when points are between X and Y.
Also you should avoid the situation when your code does not assign value to later used variable. I suggest putting decision="invalid" above the isinstance() check.
def decideReward(points):
    decision = "invalid"
    if not isinstance(points, int):
        print("Invalid input! You should provide an integer!")
    if points < 0:
        print("Invalid input! You should provide a non-negative integer!")
...

so the decision is always declared.
There is some more things you could improve reading Python tutorial in documentation or checking out this fairly decent course so you can understand the subject of your question better.

The problem is that your decideReward function is never called. Note that running a Python script will not make its functions accessible to the bash shell. In other words, if you run a script with a decideReward function, you cannot run the decideReward function in the the terminal after that. Either import the decideReward function from another program and run it:
from loyalty import decideReward
decideReward(100)

or run it directly in loyalty.py
...

decideReward(100)

